# How to Call a javascript function from html page opened in uiwebview when app comes to foreground?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using `uiwebview` in my app to display html pages within the app. I want to call `javascript` function in html page when app comes to foreground from background. I have tried using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

It is good idea to show your code if you face some issue & if you are using the webview properly and its delegate then it should call the methods properly, this is how I have been calling the jscript method and it has always worked

```
[ self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"callJsMethod();" ];
```

or sending value to the jscript method

```
 [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"callJScriptMethod('%d')", argInteger]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I Can call javascript function from button click. But I want to call that function in method applicationWillEnterForeground . But the JS function does not get called.